# database not created when run db:create with RAILS_ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Rails v2.3. and MySQL v5.1

I created a new  Rails environment named "**special**" by copy the `config/environments/development.rb` to `config/environments/special.rb`

Then, I defined the following thing in *config/database.yml* :

```
special:
   adapter: mysql2
   host: localhost
   username: My_user_name
   password: My_pwd
   database: special_db
   encoding: latin1
```

Then, I go to the command line to run the command:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=special rake db:create
```

also tried `$rake db:create RAILS_ENV=special`

I expect a new database named **special_db** should be created, but it isn't .

Why? Why I have created a new environment and run db:create in that environment, but database is not created? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the database in MySQL? 
`mysqladmin create special_db`

Are you sure that the username you are using have privileges to the database? 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON special_db.* TO 'user'@'host'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

What is the output from the rake task? Have you tried running with the -t option? If so can you post the output?